# C# search for strings in a website

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to figure out if in C# if I have converted a webpage contents into a string, what is the best way to search for extensions.  I am just looking to extract URLs within a webpage that ends in .html or .xhtml or edu. In which I don't care what the beginning looks like, which is better EndWith or Regex for finding this.

so if my input looked like this

string str = {var a,b=window.location.href.match(//webhp\?[^#]*tune=[^#]*/);if(a=b&&b.length>0?"http://www.google.com/logos/2011/lespaul.html"+b[

and i want to pull out http://www.google.com/logos/2011/lespaul.html store that into an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could come up with this Regex: `http:\/\/(.*?)(.html|.xhtml|.edu)`
Edit Thanks to @Kakashi `http:\/\/.*?\.(?:x?html|edu)`

Comment: you're creating unnecessary groups in your regex. `http:\/\/.*?\.(?:x?html|edu)`

Comment: okay i got it working with this..now here is a another question for you somthin like .php?wsdl how would you get that into regex.  I thought it was as simple http:\/\/(.*?)(.html|.xhtml|.edu|.php\?wsdl)

Comment: @user990951 I didn't get the question, perhaps you could explain it better. I would be glad to help with that as well.

Comment: i am trying to find other extensions as well.  so here are the extension i am looking for .php?wsdl (which is an extensions for wsdl)

Comment: You can add any extension of type `.php?wsdl` or `aspx` in the same Regex: `http:\/\/.*?\.(?:x?html|edu|php?wsdl|aspx)`

Answer (score 3):

You should use an HTML parser such as [sharp-query](http://code.google.com/p/sharp-query/) or [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and [never use regular expressions for parsing html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) or as the author of this post says some *things* might happen.

Comment: If you are just matching/extracting URLs regular expressions should be fine. I believe the point is parsing HTML is beyond regEx.

Comment: No, even for url parsing you should avoid regular expressions. You should use Url parsers. They are even built into the .NET framework.

Comment: What makes an expression regular?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var input = "string str = {var a,b=window.location.href.match(//webhp\\?[^#]tune=[^#]/);if(a=b&&b.length>0?\"http://www.google.com/logos/2011/lespaul.html";
var match =  Regex.Match(input, @"https?:\/{2}[^\n]+\.(?:x?html|edu)");
Console.Write(match.Success? match.Groups[0].Value : "Not found"); //http://www.google.com/logos/2011/lespaul.html
```